# Using Javascript DOM manipulation to add html elements to div

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom-manipulation

I am trying to replicate the following HTML code by using only Javascript (no jQuery).
I want the buttons to appear as a group,but it looks like they are being appended individually.
I've read up on bootstrap button groups (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) and the btn-group classs is being  called on the html. So therefore my javascript DOM manipulation is incorrect.

Can someone help me to understand why my buttons are not appearing correctly? Please note that this is only a snippet of the entire code. the HTML elements are nested in a "row" div and "container" div.

HTML

```
      <div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
var divTwo = document.createElement('div'); 
row.appendChild(divTwo);
col.appendChild(divTwo);

var btnGroupFour = document.createElement('div');
btnGroupFour.className = 'btn-group btn-group-lg';
divTwo.appendChild(btnGroupFour);


var btnLeft = document.createElement('button');
var textLeft = document.createTextNode('Left');
btnLeft.appendChild(textLeft);
btnLeft.className = 'btn btn-default';

var btnMiddle = document.createElement('button');
var textMiddle = document.createTextNode('Middle');
btnMiddle.appendChild(textMiddle);
btnMiddle.className = 'btn btn-default';

var btnRight = document.createElement('button');
var textRight = document.createTextNode('Right');
btnRight.appendChild(textRight);
btnRight.className = 'btn btn-default';

btnGroupFour.appendChild(btnLeft);
btnGroupFour.appendChild(btnMiddle);
btnGroupFour.appendChild(btnRight);
```

jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/bchang89/eh7uhs43/2/

Comment: And what is `btnGroupThree` doing there? You never add the class to `btnGroupFour`?

Comment: If you can, please provide a link to your website where this is implemented, or a replication in an instance of [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). It makes it easier to poke around to see what might be going wrong rather than looking at an isolated series of function calls.

Comment: Doing both `row.appendChild(divTwo);` and `col.appendChild(divTwo);` makes no sense.

Comment: You don't need to use jsfiddle, use [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) to embed the executable example directly into your question.

Comment: @MilesGrimes https://jsfiddle.net/bchang89/eh7uhs43/1/

Comment: @adeneo fixed! Silly mistake.

Comment: @brianchangdev Can you add the Javascript as well?

Comment: @MilesGrimes https://jsfiddle.net/bchang89/eh7uhs43/2/ 
sorry about that, added

Comment: @MilesGrimes I might have found my error. I appended buttons 5-7 to btnGroupOne

It grouped the buttons, but there still arent the spaces in between the button groups that I need

Comment: @brianchangdev are you just trying to duplicate the last set of buttons or what? Please review my answer and let me know if I'm close or not.

Comment: @zer00ne well basically I'm going to erase or comment out all the HTML.  I'm trying to replicate what the HTML would output using only javascript.

At this point everything looks good except for the fact that there isn't  spacing between the numbers groups

Comment: So you wish to generate `.container` and everything within it from scratch using only JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on the parent element `.btn-group` and set it to a deep copy. Deep copy will create a copy of the target node as well as it's descendants. The only limitation is that it will not copy any event listeners added to either the target node or it's descendants.

```
// Collect all .btn-group into a NodeList (btnGrp)
var btnGrp = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-group'); 

// Determine the last .btn-grp by using the .length property -1 
var lastGrp = btnGrp.length - 1;

// Reference the index in the btnGrp NodeList
var tgt = btnGrp[lastGrp];

// Create a clone of tgt and set the parameter to true for deep copy
var dupe = tgt.cloneNode(true);

// Append the clone to the body or any other element you wish.
document.body.appendChild(dupe);
```

**EDIT**

```
// Appendinding to `.container` since it looks better and makes more sense.
var box = document.querySelector('.container');
box.appendChild(dupe);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/fzywouuu/3/)

**Snippet**

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.container');
var btnGrp = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-group');
var lastGrp = btnGrp.length - 1;
var tgt = btnGrp[lastGrp];
var dupe = tgt.cloneNode(true);
box.appendChild(dupe);
```

```css
.btn-default {
  color: #007aff;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #007aff;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007aff;
  border-color: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">6</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">7</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">8</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```